# How to find rows from 3 months to 6 months

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my DB includes date,amount column.I would like to find rows from 3 months to 6 months using mysql query.I have tried several times but can't solved.Could u pls help me in this regard,please?Thanks in advance.
Here is my table:

id |   date   | amount |
+----+----------+--------+

|  1 | 20180218 |   1200 |
|  2 | 20190518 |   1500 |
|  3 | 20180127 |   1400 |
+----+----------+--------+

Expected Output Would Be:

SL No. |   Less Than 3 Months  | 3 Months To 6 Months |
+--------+----------------------------+------------------------------+

|  1 | 1200     |   1500 |
|  2 | 1400 |   0.00 |
|  3 | 0.00 |   0.00 |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+

And sorry,for poor table design.

Comment: you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..  otherwise you question is not clear ..  and also add  the code you have tried

Comment: Hi,thanks for ur response.Actually,I also want to know what would be the output if I want to find rows from 3 to 6 months in respect to current date.And I tried to add data sample but it was not properly showed.

Comment: I'm not in your mind and is impossible for me imagine your need  so  update your question and add  the data sample and the expected  result ...

Comment: Provide table structure and datatype of columns in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your date is a varchar  of format `'20180823'` 
You could use a date_sub and a proper date conversion

```
select * 
from my_table  
where sr_to_date(date,'%Y%m%d') 
      between   DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
          and DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```